# How MAX(Calendar[date]) -as a filter in CALCULATE- evaluates to the current context date when calculating running total?

Tags: dax

[This](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/computing-running-totals-in-dax/) Article by Alberto Ferrari shows how to compute the running total over a dimension:

```
Sales RT :=
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) -- Saves the last visible date
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Sales Amount],            -- Computes sales amount
        'Date'[Date] <= MaxDate,   -- Where date is before the last visible date
        ALL ( Date )               -- Removes any other filters from Date
    )
```

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gf3eueRD_g)

he says: "Maxdate contains the last date that is visible in the context"

Where did the context come from when we are using **ALL(Date)** which cancels all filters and returns the entire Date table?
Shouldn't Max(Date) be always equal to the Maximum date of the entire Date table? not the one corresponding to the row being calculated.
What is meant by [visible context] hear? how is it defined? And/or how is it treated by CALCULATE when ALL is used?

If anyone please could explain to me -in depth- how the [MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )] evaluated to the date corresponding to the row being calculated and not to the Maximum date of the entire Date table

Thanks.

Comment: Variables are calculated *within the scope in which they are written*. Their result is stored and used in the rest of the expression. There are many good sources of explanation as to this behaviour, for example https://radacad.com/caution-when-using-variables-in-dax-and-power-bi

Comment: but Some don't even use a variable, they do the following:

calcualte([sales amount], filter(All(calender), calendar[date] <= max(calendar[date])))